# Convert scanf to a different argument size

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following to print a character entered by the user (using `int` to allow `EOF` in other places):

```
int ch;
scanf("%d", &ch);
printf("The character you entered was: %c\n", (char) ch);
```

Here, I am converting to a `char` in the `printf` function. How would I do that in the `scanf` function instead? For example, something like:

```
int ch;
scanf("%c", & (char) ch); // ???
printf("The character you entered was: %c\n", ch);
```

How would that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would scan a `char` and afterward convert it to `int`:

```
char c;
int ch;

if (scanf(" %c", &c) == 1) {
    ch = (unsigned char) c;
} else {
    ch = EOF;
}
```

The explicit conversion to `unsigned char` produces a result analogous to `getchar()`'s.  There is a subsequent automatic conversion from that result to type `int`.  In the case where `scanf()` fails to scan a character (other than leading whitespace), `ch` is set explicitly to `EOF`, much as `getchar()` would do.

Note also that the given format explicitly skips leading whitespace, as `%d` and most other format directives automatically do, but `%c` does not.  This is for consistency with your `%d` variation -- it is *not* what `getchar()` does.

If you scan just one `char` into an otherwise uninitialized `int`, then you may not use the resulting `int` value without evoking undefined behavior on account of the three indeterminate bytes.  Even if you initialized your `int` first -- to zero, say -- scanning one byte into it does not necessarily produce an `int` with the same value as that `char`, so no, no trick with scanning directly to the `int` is reliable.  Theoretical UB aside, that could not be expected to work as you want on a big-endian machine or if the integer value of the scanned character were negative.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done.

In

```
scanf("%c", xxx);
```

the xxx part simply *must* be an expression of type pointer-to-`char`.

So you must either do

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
```

or, if you really want to get it into an `int` variable, you're going to have to do something like

```
int i;
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
i = c;
```

If you were to try to do

```
scanf("%c", (char *)&i);     /* WRONG */
```

you're doing something that's at best squirrelly and at worst (in other, related cases) downright undefined.  It might seem to work, but it would be quite wrong.

For example, I just tried

```
int i = 0x01020304;
scanf("%c", (char *)&i);      /* WRONG */
printf("i = %c\n", i);
printf("i = %d = %x\n", i, i);
```

and typed "X".  The first `printf` printed `i = X`, so it seemed to work.  But the second `printf` printed `i = 16909176 = 1020378`, which is certainly *not* the ASCII value of the character `'X'`!  On a big-endian machine, it probably would have worked even less well.

Why doesn't it work?  Well, `scanf` and `%c` expect an argument of type pointer-to-`char`, because `%c` is going to fill in precisely one value of type `char`.  If you say

```
scanf("%c", &i);       /* WRONG */
```

it's wrong, and a conscientious compiler will typically warn you with something like "warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int *'".  If you try to shut the compiler up, by writing

```
scanf("%c", (char *)&i);       /* WRONG */
```

the cast will indeed make the warning go away, and now we're left with the problem that we started with a pointer-to-`int`, and we're pretending it's a pointer-to-`char`.  `scanf` will play along with the game, but: it will use the pointer to fill in *only one byte* of the `int` variable, leaving the rest completely alone.

Comment: ok, but what about doing `scanf("%c", (char*) &ch);` ?

Comment: thanks, could you explain though why the last option is wrong? What would be an example where it wouldn't work?

Comment: The last snippet is not undefined behaviour;  just may or may not give desired results.   (Although it is UB to print `i` with `%x` specifier, you can fix that with a cast)

Comment: @M.M. True in this case, but only because `char *` is special.  False for, say, using `%d` to read a variable of type `char`.

Comment: @carl.hiass You should maybe stop thinking of casts like `(char *)` as magic bullets that make things work.  They are usually (and in this case exactly are) magic bullets that make warnings go away.  But the warning was correctly telling you that something *would not work*.  With the cast, it still doesn't work, and you don't even get the warning.

Comment: I'm generally inclined to think that casts for other than arithmetic purposes have potent code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always do this:

```
int ch;
scanf("%c",(char*) &ch);
printf("you entered %c\n",ch);
```

Comment: You could do that, but it would not be reliable.  At minimum there is a problem with the fact that not all bytes of `ch` are initialized.